# Deserialize JSON returned from external Url into an Object

Tags: arrays, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, serialization

Ok so my json return string looks like this:

```
  {
    "categories": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "category": "cat-1"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "category": "cat-2"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "category": "cat-3"
      }
    ]
  }
```

This list of returned categories is going to be used as a dropdown in my bootstrap nav menu so I would like to use the least amount of calls as possible as it will likely not change often enough to have to all it during each page refresh if I don't have to.

How would I write out my Model/ViewModel to bind to this string? I would then like to use something like this to return a list of CategoryViewModel from which I can iterate through.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel>> GetCategoryList () {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync ("/categories");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode ();

        var result = await response.Content
            .ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel>> ();

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The JSON model you have requires a container class, for example:

```
public class CategoryViewModelContainer
{
    public IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel> Categories { get; set; }
}

//Assuming your category view model looks like this:
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<CategoryViewModelContainer>();
```

Now you can loop through the categories:

```
foreach(var categoryModel in result.Categories)
{
    var categoryName = categoryModel.Category;
}
```

Comment: Quick to respond and logical explanation that I'm going to attempt to make this work. I'm a bit rusty getting back into things so your help is greatly appreciated. I'll be back with the results.